# Installing gcc on linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, devtoolset

How to install gcc version 4.8 on centos or scientific linux operating systems which require yum for installing.

I tried to download gcc from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.8.2/ and then ran ./configure and then make. After running make it gives me the error: configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.

Is there some way by which I may install gcc version 4.8 on linux using yum install

I tried:
1). I tried with `yum --enablerepo=testing-2-devtools-6 install devtoolset-2-gcc devtoolset-2-gcc-c++` it gives me repository not found

2). `yum group install "Development Tools"`. It gives me Package gcc-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version

3).  building it from scratch, you'll have to do ./contrib/download_prerequisites first to get MPFR, GMP and MPC in the GCC source tree, then make a separate directory and run /path/to/gcc/source/configure.
It gives:

> configure: error: building out of tree but /home/Softwares/gcc-4.8.2
>   contains host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Comment: If you insist on building it from scratch, you'll have to do ```./contrib/download_prerequisites``` first to get MPFR, GMP and MPC in the GCC source tree, then make a separate directory and run ```/path/to/gcc/source/configure``` - GCC needs to build MPFR, GMP and MPC at the same time, and doesn't support in source builds (last time I tried it).

Comment: @CommanderCorianderSalamander I tried that but it gives me: configure: error: building out of tree but /home/Softwares/gcc-4.8.2 contains host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Answer (score 2):

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/3/html/3.0_Release_Notes/DTS3.0_Release.html#Features
Install the Red Hat Developer Toolset 3.0 (or 2.X) in a way similar to what is described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos). (Basically you use a repo someone else built for CentOS).

Comment: I tried with yum --enablerepo=testing-2-devtools-6 install devtoolset-2-gcc devtoolset-2-gcc-c++ it gives me repository not found

Answer (score 1):

Google says to try

```
yum group install "Development Tools"
```

check out: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-7-redhat-linux-install-gcc-compiler-development-tools/

Comment: It gives me Package gcc-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: Hmmm...  You could try uninstalling with "yum group remove {groupname}" then try again, or use --exclude option to install everything else.  Also, I'm seeing "group install" as well as "groupinstall" both being used.