# Error while installing gcc 4.8 on scientific linux 6

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

Whenever I try to install gcc 4.8 on scientific linux 6 I get the following error. Does anyone know any fix for the error:

```
[root@ABC]# yum install libstdc++-devel.i686
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/6.6/x86_64/RPMS/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: testing-devtools-2-centos-6.6. Please verify its path and try again
```

EDIT: yum repolist
OUTPUT:

```
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/6.6/x86_64/RPMS/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/6.6/x86_64/RPMS/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
repo id                       repo name                                      status
sl                            Scientific Linux 6.6 - x86_64                  6,665
sl-security                   Scientific Linux 6.6 - x86_64 - security updat   420
sl6x                          Scientific Linux 6x - x86_64                   6,665
sl6x-security                 Scientific Linux 6x - x86_64 - security update   420
testing-devtools-2-centos-6.6 testing 2 devtools for CentOS 6.6                  0
repolist: 14,170
```

EDIT: wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-devtoolset.repo http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/devtoolset/slc6-devtoolset.repo
OUTPUT:

```
--2015-04-22 13:05:01--  http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/devtoolset/slc6-devtoolset.repo
Resolving linuxsoft.cern.ch... 2001:1458:201:95::100:13, 2001:1458:201:95::100:14, 2001:1458:201:95::100:d, ...
Connecting to linuxsoft.cern.ch|2001:1458:201:95::100:13|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to linuxsoft.cern.ch|2001:1458:201:95::100:14|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to linuxsoft.cern.ch|2001:1458:201:95::100:d|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
```

Comment: I believe the error is pretty straightforward here. You're trying to get a package that doesn't exist anymore (hence the 404). Did you update your repository list?

Comment: @meneldal I am new to scientific linux therefore I dont know how I can update the repository list. Can you please guide me..I tried yum update...still I got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install the `Devtoolset-repo` on your host

   `wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-devtoolset.repo http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/devtoolset/slc6-devtoolset.repo`
2. Install the devtoolset `yum install devtoolset-2`
3. Test installed environment

   ```
   scl enable devtoolset-2 bash 
   gcc --version
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also can you please guide me as to how can I install gcc 4.8 on Scientific Linux. I tried a lot (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786528/installing-gcc-on-linux) but none helped

Comment: Hi..sorry but I am still getting the same error...so this does not help

Comment: I tried wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-devtoolset.repo http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/devtoolset/slc6-devtoolset.repo
 but it gives me: Resolving linuxsoft.cern.ch... 2001:1458:201:95::100:10, 2001:1458:201:95::100:11, 2001:1458:201:95::100:12, ...
Connecting to linuxsoft.cern.ch|2001:1458:201:95::100:10|:80... failed: Connection timed out.

Comment: I have added the full output to the question as it was long

Comment: Apparently smth is wrong with your network setup. For me the repo is reachable.

Try with following lookup ip adresses Lookup Hostname: linuxsoft.cern.ch
`Lookup IP Address: 137.138.18.157
Lookup IP Address: 137.138.18.158
Lookup IP Address: 137.138.18.151
Lookup IP Address: 137.138.18.152
Lookup IP Address: 137.138.18.153
Lookup IP Address: 137.138.18.154
Lookup IP Address: 137.138.18.155
Lookup IP Address: 137.138.18.156`

Comment: Sorry i am new to linux how can I lookup an ip address

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75902/discussion-between-deimus-and-steg-verner).

Comment: Try `wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-devtoolset.repo http://137.138.18.157/cern/devtoolset/slc6-devtoolset.repo`

Comment: Thanks a lot..it is seemingly downloading files. But this is magic..how can ip address work and linuxsoft.cern.ch does not...

Comment: Glad to hear thats is ok now. Smth is messed up with your `DNS` or `IP6` setup